# VB.NET Webbrowser to textbox

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox, browser

I need help getting all of the text from WebBrowser1 to my textbox1.text

I tried

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox3.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
```

textbox3 being my website
and textbox1 being were i want all the text.

Comment: Use `WebClient` instead.

Comment: `.Navigate` **starts** the navigation so you need to extract the contents when the navigation is complete and the document has been loaded

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the `DocumentCompleted` event of `WebBrowser` control.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, 
       e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) 
              Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
  TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' WebBrowser1
        ' TextBox1
        ' TextBox2
        '
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True      ' we would like to suppress scripts error message
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://codeguru.com")

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        ' 1) Get entire html code and save as .html file
        TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

        ' HOWTO retry while error UNTIL ok
        ' this needs to be done because Body.InnerText returns error when called too soon
        ' 2) Get Body text and save as .txt file
        Dim retry As Boolean = True
        Dim body As String = ""
        While retry
            Try
                body = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
                retry = False
            Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
                retry = True
            Finally
                TextBox2.Text = body
            End Try
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```